# Counting page views with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to implement page view counter in my app. What I've done so far is using this method :

```
public function showpost($titleslug) {
        $post = Post::where('titleslug','=',$titleslug)->firstOrFail();
        $viewed = Session::get('viewed_post', []);
        if (!in_array($post->id, $viewed)) {
            $post->increment('views');
            Session::push('viewed_post', $post->id);
        }
        return view('posts/show', compact('post', $post));
    }
```

I retrieve the popular posts list like this :

```
$popular_posts = Post::orderBy('views', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```

However, I'd like to know if there are any better ways to do this ? And with my current method, can I get a list of most viewed posts in the past 24 hours ? That's all and thanks!

Comment: If you do store when a page was viewed you can get that information but if you only use a counter for the amount of times a post was viewed you cannot sort by most viewed in last x minutes.

Comment: How big is the "app" (I would say web page instead), in other words how many users is the peak? Or if you have stats, how many req/m during the peak? What session driver do you use? Is the page view relevant only to show most viewed pages or you will use data later on (perhaps "30 days ago top 10 articles/pages" and so on...).

Comment: Well, that means I need to create a different table to store the views data. @milo526

Comment: Not big at all, I'm building a blog and it still in development so I don't have any visitors related data to analyze yet. I want to use the view counter to get the most popular posts, and trending posts (sorted by most viewed posts in the past x hours) @Kyslik

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As quoted in @ milo526's comment, you can record all hits to your pages in a unique way instead of an increment. With this you have many possibilities to search for access information, including the listing of the posts sorted by most viewed.

Create a table to save your view records:

```
Schema::create("posts_views", function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";

            $table->increments("id");
            $table->increments("id_post");
            $table->string("titleslug");
            $table->string("url");
            $table->string("session_id");
            $table->string("user_id");
            $table->string("ip");
            $table->string("agent");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Then, create the corresponding model:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

class PostsViews extends \Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'posts_views';

    public static function createViewLog($post) {
            $postsViews= new PostsViews();
            $postsViews->id_post = $post->id;
            $postsViews->titleslug = $post->titleslug;
            $postsViews->url = \Request::url();
            $postsViews->session_id = \Request::getSession()->getId();
            $postsViews->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
            $postsViews->ip = \Request::getClientIp();
            $postsViews->agent = \Request::header('User-Agent');
            $postsViews->save();
    }

}
```

Finally, your method:

```
public function showpost($titleslug)
{
    $post = PostsViews::where('titleslug', '=' ,$titleslug)->firstOrFail();

    PostsViews::createViewLog($post);

    //Rest of method...
}
```

To search the most viewed posts in the last 24 hours:

```
$posts = Posts::join("posts_views", "posts_views.id_post", "=", "posts.id")
            ->where("created_at", ">=", date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-24 hours', time())))
            ->groupBy("posts.id")
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(posts.id)', 'desc'))
            ->get(array(DB::raw('COUNT(posts.id) as total_views'), 'posts.*'));
```

Note that in PostsViews, you have data that can help further filter your listing, such as the session id, in case you do not want to consider hits from the same session.

You may need to adapt some aspects of this solution to your final code.

Comment: I'll try this, but I'm wondering do I have to define relationship between the `post_views` table and the `posts` table ?

Comment: I had to change a few things but you gave me the idea, I'll post my modified version here when it's done. Thanks!

Comment: This is a great concept! I've also adapted it slightly for a project that I'm working on. You might consider updating createViewLog() to call $postsViews->save(). Otherwise the log entry will not be inserted into the table.

Comment: Awesome answer..super amazing +1. Few things I have noticed which I have posted a separate answer, as there was a scope to make it better. Thanks a lot for this awesome answer again, saved my day.

Answer (score 11):

### 2020 Update

First of all, thanks a lot "Jean Marcos" for his awesome answer. All credit goes to him, I am just pasting a slightly modified answer combining my knowledge of Laravel as well.

Create a table to save your view records and name it with **snake_case plural: post_views**

```
Schema::create("post_views", function(Blueprint $table)
{
      $table->engine = "InnoDB";//this is basically optional as you are not using foreign key relationship so you could go with MyISAM as well

      $table->increments("id");
      
      //please note to use integer NOT increments as "Jean Marcos' answer" because it will throw error "Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key" when running migration.
      $table->unsignedInteger("post_id");//note that the Laravel way of defining foreign keys is "table-singular-name_id", so it's preferable to use that
      
      $table->string("titleslug");
      $table->string("url");
      $table->string("session_id");
      $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();//here note to make it nullable if your page is accessible publically as well not only by logged in users. Also its more appropriate to have "unsignedInteger" type instead of "string" type as mentioned in Jean Marcos' answer because user_id will save same data as id field of users table which in most cases will be an auto incremented id.
      $table->string("ip");
      $table->string("agent");
      $table->timestamps();
});
```

Then, create the corresponding model. **Please note to create "PascalCase" model name and singular form of the table** so it should be like: **PostView**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PostView extends Model
{
    public static function createViewLog($post) {
        $postViews= new PostView();
        $postViews->listing_id = $post->id;
        $postViews->url = \Request::url();
        $postViews->session_id = \Request::getSession()->getId();
        $postViews->user_id = (\Auth::check())?\Auth::id():null; //this check will either put the user id or null, no need to use \Auth()->user()->id as we have an inbuild function to get auth id
        $postViews->ip = \Request::getClientIp();
        $postViews->agent = \Request::header('User-Agent');
        $postViews->save();//please note to save it at lease, very important
    }
}
```

Then run the migration to generate this table

```
php artisan migrate
```

Finally, your method:

```
public function showpost($titleslug)
{
    $post = PostView::where('titleslug', '=' ,$titleslug)->firstOrFail();

    \App\PostView::createViewLog($post);//or add `use App\PostView;` in beginning of the file in order to use only `PostView` here 

    //Rest of method...
}
```

To search the most viewed posts in the last 24 hours:

```
$posts = Posts::join("post_views", "post_views.id_post", "=", "posts.id")
            ->where("created_at", ">=", date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-24 hours', time())))
            ->groupBy("posts.id")
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(posts.id)'), 'desc')//here its very minute mistake of a paranthesis in Jean Marcos' answer, which results ASC ordering instead of DESC so be careful with this line
            ->get([DB::raw('COUNT(posts.id) as total_views'), 'posts.*']);
```

Note that in PostView, you have data that can help further filter your listing, such as the session id, in case you do not want to consider hits from the same session.

You may need to adapt some aspects of this solution to your final code.

So those were few modifications I wanted to point out, also you might want to put an additional column `client_internet_ip` in which you can store `\Request::ip()` which can be used as a filter as well if required.

*I hope it helps*

Answer (score 11):

**2020 Update (2)/ With Eloquent Relationships for Laravel 6**

If you don't want to add a package to your application. I have developed the following solution based on "Jean Marcos" and "Learner" contribution to the question and my own research.

All credit goes to "Jean Marcos" and "Learner",  I felt like I should do the same as Learner and update the code in a way the would be beneficial to others.

First of all, make sure you have a sessions table in the database. Otherwise, follow the steps in Laravel documentations to do so: [HTTP Session](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session)

Make sure that the sessions are stored in the table. If not, make sure to change the SESSION_DRIVER variable at the .env set to 'database' not 'file' and do composer dump-autoload afterwards.

After that, you are all set to go. You can start by running the following console command:

```
php artisan make:model PostView -m
```

This will generate both the model and migration files.

Inside of the migration file put the following Schema. Be cautious with the columns names. For example, my posts table have the "slug" column title name instead of the "titleslug" which was mentioned in the question.

```
  Schema::create('post_views', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments("id");
        $table->unsignedInteger("post_id");
        $table->string("titleslug");
        $table->string("url");
        $table->string("session_id");
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->string("ip");
        $table->string("agent");
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Then put the following code inside the PostView model file.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PostView extends Model
{

    public function postView()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }

    public static function createViewLog($post) {
        $postViews= new PostView();
        $postViews->post_id = $post->id;
        $postViews->slug = $post->slug;
        $postViews->url = request()->url();
        $postViews->session_id = request()->getSession()->getId();
        $postViews->user_id = (auth()->check())?auth()->id():null; 
        $postViews->ip = request()->ip();
        $postViews->agent = request()->header('User-Agent');
        $postViews->save();
    }
}
```

Now inside the Post model write the following code. This to create the relation between the posts table and the post_views table.

```
use App\PostView;

   public function postView()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PostView::class);
    }
```

In the same Post model you should put the following code. If the user is not logged in the the code will test the IP match. Otherwise, it will test both the session ID and the user ID as each user might have multiple sessions.

```
public function showPost()
{
    if(auth()->id()==null){
        return $this->postView()
        ->where('ip', '=',  request()->ip())->exists();
    }

    return $this->postView()
    ->where(function($postViewsQuery) { $postViewsQuery
        ->where('session_id', '=', request()->getSession()->getId())
        ->orWhere('user_id', '=', (auth()->check()));})->exists();  
}
```

You are ready now to run the migration.

```
php artisan migrate
```

When the user ask for the post. The following function should be targeted inside the PostController file:

```
use App\PostView;

     public function show(Post $post)
        {
//Some bits from the following query ("category", "user") are made for my own application, but I felt like leaving it for inspiration. 
            $post = Post::with('category', 'user')->withCount('favorites')->find($post->id);

            if($post->showPost()){// this will test if the user viwed the post or not
                return $post;
            }

            $post->increment('views');//I have a separate column for views in the post table. This will increment the views column in the posts table.
            PostView::createViewLog($post);
            return $post;
        }
```

As I have a separate column for views in the post table. To search the most viewed posts in the last 24 hours you write this code in the controller. Remove paginate if you don't have pagination:

```
public function mostViwedPosts()
{
    return Posts::with('user')->where('created_at','>=', now()->subdays(1))->orderBy('views', 'desc')->latest()->paginate(5);
}
```

I hope this would help/save someones time.

Comment: `$productsViews->session_id = request()->getSession()->getId();`
returns **null**,

tried to `dd(request());` and it show that the whole **session** property is null
what should I do?

Comment: Note that I'm using this method for api and web, it works on the web but is it perfect on the api?

Comment: Hi @WailHayaly make sure you got your session configuration right [link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session#configuration) and give it a composer dumb-autoload , php artisan cache:clear and php artisan config:clear in your console.

Comment: And does it operate on the API? 
because I'm using a mobile application to get json, so I think there's no session in here

Comment: RuntimeException:
Session store not set on request.

Comment: Im getting `SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value:`

Answer (score 6):

[Eloquent Viewable](https://github.com/cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable) package can be used for this purpose. It provides more flexible ways to do stuff like this(counting page views).

> Note:The Eloquent Viewable package requires PHP 7+ and Laravel 5.5+.

**Make Model viewable:**

Just add the **Viewable** trait to the model definition like:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use CyrildeWit\EloquentViewable\Viewable;

class Post extends Model
{
    use Viewable;

    // ...
}
```

**Then in the controller:**

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    $post->addView();

    return view('blog.post', compact('post'));
}
```

After that you can do stuff like this:(**[see package installation guide for more details](https://github.com/cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable)**)

```
// Get the total number of views
$post->getViews();

// Get the total number of views since the given date
$post->getViews(Period::since(Carbon::parse('2014-02-23 00:00:00')));

// Get the total number of views between the given date range
$post->getViews(Period::create(Carbon::parse('2014-00-00 00:00:00'), Carbon::parse('2016-00-00 00:00:00')));

// Get the total number of views in the past 6 weeks (from today)
$post->getViews(Period::pastWeeks(6));

// Get the total number of views in the past 2 hours (from now)
$post->getViews(Period::subHours(2));

// Store a new view in the database
$post->addView();
```

Implements same kind of idea as in the accepted answer, but provides more features and flexibilities.

Comment: I am not understanding how to setup the controller if I dont have a `$post`, `Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Post] does not exist. `

Comment: @weber, controller name is supposed to be 'NameController', i.e 'PostController'. You can generate a controller by this artisan command: php artisan make:controller PostControlller -r

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to user33192 for sharing the [eloquent viewable](https://github.com/cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable). Just want to make it clearer for others after looking at the docs. Look at the docs to install the package.

Do this in your **Post** Model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use CyrildeWit\EloquentViewable\InteractsWithViews;
use CyrildeWit\EloquentViewable\Viewable;

class Post extends Model implements Viewable
{
    use InteractsWithViews;

    // ...
}
```

In your **posts** controller, use the record method to save a view;

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $post = Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();
    views($post)->record();
    return view('posts.show',compact('post'));
}
```

In your views you can return the **views** (mine is **posts.show**) as you want. Check the document for more. I will just the total views of a post.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
    {{ views($post)->count() }} <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
</button>
```