# Creating page views with Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a page view counter for my recipe application in Laravel. I've been using this SO post as a guide: [Counting page views with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422497/counting-page-views-with-laravel)

However, when I try to access my recipes, it gives me a 404 error. Could someone please take a look and see what is going wrong? Thank you!

**Migration**

```
Schema::create('recipe_views', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->unsignedInteger("recipe_id");
            $table->string("titleslug");
            $table->string("url");
            $table->string("session_id");
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->string("ip");
            $table->string("agent");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Model**

```
class RecipeView extends Model
{
    public static function createViewLog($recipe) {
        $recipeViews= new RecipeView();
        $recipeViews->listing_id = $recipe->id;
        $recipeViews->url = \Request::url();
        $recipeViews->session_id = \Request::getSession()->getId();
        $recipeViews->user_id = (\Auth::check())?\Auth::id():null;
        $recipeViews->ip = \Request::getClientIp();
        $recipeViews->agent = \Request::header('User-Agent');
        $recipeViews->save();
    }
}
```

**Recipe Controller**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $recipeView = RecipeView::where('id', '=' ,$id)->firstOrFail();
        RecipeView::createViewLog($recipeView);

        $recipe = Recipe::find($id);
        $ingredients = explode("\n", $recipe->ingredients);
        $directions = explode("\n", $recipe->directions);

        return view('recipes.show')->with('recipe', $recipe)->with('directions', $directions)->with('ingredients', $ingredients);
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('/recipes', 'RecipesController');
```

Would really appreciate some help on this. I'm a little lost as to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: In the `Recipe Controller` - can you change  firstOrFail(); to first(); and log the result via dd($recipeView ); (can you show me the route file?)

Comment: looks like it is a route error

Comment: @KoenHollander the route I have for recipes is a resource route, I have added it to the question. The route list has "recipes/{recipe}" under the show route, where {recipe} is the recipe id. The dd($recipeView) return null

Comment: Can you see if the insert happened in DB? Can you try to use ->all() instead of firstOrFail() ?

Comment: @DanishHakimKhan it tells me that ->all() is call to an undefined function. Any ideas why? There was no insert into the DB no..

Comment: If there is no save in DB then how can you fetch? You mentioned above that dd($recepieView) return null, it mean there is no record found. And then you are passing null to model to save some data in ViewLog, so, definitely it won't because the ID you are trying to view is not there in DB. Put a check in controller if(!$recipeView->isEmpty){ RecipeView::createViewLog($recipeView); } else { dd('not found'); that way you will get an output of what is going on

Comment: @DanishHakimKhan that check doesn't give me an output of what is going on, it gives me the 404 page again. I know it isn't working. That is why I posted the question. I'm not able to fetch it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see if your /index.php/recipes works?

If yes, you need to fix with following steps

1. In a terminal use the following commands:

> $ sudo a2enmod rewrite

2. Change AllowOverride in apache conf file:

> $ sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Change the AllowOverride from None to All in this block

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

3. At last, restart apache2

> $ sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify function name+variable in your route. In your case show()

```
resource('/recipes/{id}', 'RecipesController@show');
```

Comment: It's a resource route. It doesn't need me to define that. Laravel does that under the hood

Comment: That's for sure problem with route. Check it twice.